Match arrays to return one or more columns in Google Sheets
What is the best easily adaptable formula for returning one or more values based on a matching ID # in google sheets?
the goal formula would be the most efficient way to specify 2 sheets with matching rows and desired return columns
formulaX(Sheet1!array, Sheet2!array, col1, [col8, …], [col2, …])

Normally, you could use arrayformula+vlookup together as in the tables below:
For example, if I one sheet named 'database' and a second named 'lookup' where lookup has matching ID numbers in col a, I could use 1 arrayformula vlookup for every value I want to lookup
arrayformula(IFERROR(vlookup(A:A, database!A:F,2,false)))

but this results in more complexity and isnt very efficient if I want to match multiple values.
Database



ID
First
Last
Birthday
Siblings
Age




AB
Jack
Messi
01/01/19
Maria, Mary
5


CD
Jack
Smith
01/02/19

5


EF
Sam
Messi
02/01/19
Tara, James, Billy
5


GH
Samatha
Reynoldo
03/02/19
Andrea
5


IJ
John
Jordan
04/01/19

5


KL
Jamie
Bryant
05/02/18
Jack, Michael, Elizabeth
5


MN
Janie
Oneil
01/01/17

7











LOOKUP



ID
First
Age




AB
Jack
5


CD
Jack
5


EF
Sam
5


IJ
John
5








the above uses this example uses in b2, c2=arrayformula(IFERROR(vlookup(A:A, database!A:G,2,false))), arrayformula(IFERROR(vlookup(A:A, database!A:G,5,false)))
Possible functions

Query()
Index() + Match()
Byrow()
lamda()

because index and match are in-built they might be faster or more efficient than using a lamda() inside of google sheets

Assuming the data is in A2:F and the search keys are in I2:I, you can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I2:I,A2:F,{2,6},0)))


You could also define a custom function ZLOOKUP with 3 arguments, key, range, labels:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(key,range,XMATCH(labels,INDEX(range,1)),0)))

And use it as follows:
=ZLOOKUP(I2:I,A:F,J1:K1)



this seems right, working almost like an index of columns to return and adding additional comma delimiter will return an expandable number of columns retruned

I don't get it, does this answer your question? I also edited my answer with an alternative solution.
